# Use dplyr complete with categories

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset containing values for counts of different species at different sites.  This dataset does not include the sites where species were surveyed for, but not found (count = 0).  I'm trying to use the dplyr complete function to fill in all the sites, but I keep receiving the following error message:

```
Error: `by` can't contain join column `site %in% possibleSites` which is missing from RHS
```

A sample dataset is provided below.

NOTE: my actual data includes additional information, such as the latitude and longitude for these different sites, time of day, etc. that I also need to include in my final dataset.

```
species <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5))
site <- rep(sample(letters[1:10], 5, replace = FALSE), 3)
count <- sample(1:50, 15, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(species, site, count)

possibleSites <- letters[1:10]

df %>% 
  complete(site %in% possibleSites,
           nesting(species),
           fill = list(count = 0))
```

I would appreciate help fixing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
df %>% 
  complete(site = possibleSites, 
           species,
           fill = list(count = 0)
           )
```

Output:

```
   site species count
1     a       A    19
2     a       B    10
3     a       C    44
4     b       A     0
5     b       B     0
6     b       C     0
7     c       A    44
8     c       B     1
9     c       C     7
10    d       A     0
11    d       B     0
12    d       C     0
13    e       A     0
14    e       B     0
15    e       C     0
16    f       A    40
17    f       B     5
18    f       C    20
19    g       A    25
20    g       B    12
21    g       C     9
22    h       A     0
23    h       B     0
24    h       C     0
25    i       A    47
26    i       B    33
27    i       C     4
28    j       A     0
29    j       B     0
30    j       C     0
```

Comment: Yes!  Works perfectly.  I'll accept you answer in 6 minutes.